# Animation GUI with curves for iPhone animation

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, animation

Greetings fellow stackoverflow users,
I'm making an iPhone app and our animator is from a 3D animation background. He knows how to code, but he's used to using programs to animate (like Flash or Maya).

Is there some library or program that would let him animate using key frames and curves and would be easy to import into our iPhone app?. Or at the very least is there some library that behaves like jQuery where you can select the easing for animations and chain them together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unity3d](http://unity3d.com/) is usually a good place to start for people with a Maya background.  It will also allow you to import assets directly from Maya without having to build your own graphics pipeline.

Comment: In this context you can treat 2d as a subset of 3d: just use an orthographic camera in Unity.  The Maya models can be 3d-rendered-as-2d or hierarchical connections of 2d planes with textures ( this is how, eg, South Park is done. Google '2d animation maya' and you'll see lots of options